# Triggers con sentencias preparadas MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

que tal chicos. Apenas estoy leyendo sobre los Triggers, sin embargo no he encontrado nada para implementarlos juntos con las sentencias preparadas de mysqli como insert, update o delete. Tengo la siguiente sentencia preparada.

```
$ticket_upd = $this->connection->prepare(UPDATE pl_tickets SET id_seller = ?, state_ticket = ? WHERE num_ticket = ? AND id_lot = ?);
$ticket_upd->bind_param("isii", $id_seller, $state_ticket, $num_ticket, $id_lot);
$ticket_upd->execute();
$ticket_upd->close();
```

Que sucede... quiero hacer un log para registrar las acciones de los usuarios, como cuando hacen un ingreso, o actualizan alguna celda con en este caso, incluso cuando se borran registros. Quiero que toda acción quede en una bitácora o log. No soy muy experto, aún estoy aprendiendo, y me gustaría implementar los triggers en vez de hacer una inserción normal en la tabla log cada vez que se realiza una de las acciones antes nombrada.

De antemano, muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Si has leído sobre los `TRIGGER` habrás entendido que son acciones que se lanzan de forma automática al ocurrir algo en una determinada tabla. Por ejemplo `CREATE TRIGGER onTicketUpdate AFTER UPDATE ON pl_tickets FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN INSERT INTO log_tickets (num_ticket, log_time) VALUES(NEW.num_ticket, NOW()) ; END;` Hará una inserción en la tabla `log_tickets` cada vez que un registro sea actualizado en `pl_tickets`. Ese `INSERT` pondra en `log_tickets` dos valores: `num_ticket` y el valor de `NOW()` en dos columnas respectivas que se suponen que existen.

Comment: Hola A. Cedano, gracias por la explicación. A ver si voy entendiendo mejor, es decir, los triggers solo se crean la primera vez y ya no hay que volver a llamar al trigger, es algo automático al detectar las inserciones o updates respectivos. Ya solo quedaría establecer las condiciones al trigger, para que inserte en la tabla log 'x' valor si el insert presenta un valor en el $state_ticket y asi sucesivamente con otras variables. Muchas gracias. Intentaré a ver que tal me va.

Comment: Es correcto. El `TRIGGER` se crea una sola vez y se lanza cuando ocurra esa acción. Si es `AFTER UPDATE ON pl_tickets` significa que se lanzara cada vez, después (AFTER)  que ocurra una actualización (UPDATE) en la tabla pl_tickets (ON pl_tickets).

Comment: Mil gracias A. Cedano.

Comment: ¿Pudiste hacerlo?

Comment: Aún no lo intento, ahora estoy leyendo sobre como pasar variables de sesion al trigger. Entonces he observado que se guarda la variable de sesion en una variable y luego se hace un query de la siguiente forma.

$this->connection->query("SET @user_id = $user_id") 

Lo anterior por que no siempre en los insert o update hay ciertos datos que si van para el log pero que estan en variables de sesion.  No se si es lo correcto.